# Javascript split array into n subarrays, size of chunks don't matter

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I want to split an array into n subarrays.
I don't care how many elements end up in each array but the elements must be spread through all the available sub arrays.

Like this, solutions A & B are two ways of doing it but **I'm looking for Solution A**:

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

into_subarrays(a, 2);

- Solution A => [[1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8]]
- Solution B => [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]

into_subarrays(a, 4);

- Solution A => [[1,5,9],[2,6],[3,7],[4,8]]
- Solution B => [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]]

into_subarrays(a, 6);

- Solution A => [[1,7],[2,8],[3,9],[4],[5],[6]]
- Solution B => [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7],[8],[9]]

into_subarrays(a, 12);

- Solution A => [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[],[],[]]
- Solution B => [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[],[],[]]

I have this solution, I just want to make sure it's as efficient as possible:

```
into_subarrays(myArray, chunks=2){
  var a = myArray.slice(); //Copy array so that the original is not modified
  var i = 0;
  var result = [];
          
  while(a.length){
   //Create array if needed
   if (typeof result[i] == 'undefined'){
     result[i] = [];
   }

   result[i].push(a.shift());
   i++;
   i = (i == chunks) ? 0 : i; //Wrap around chunk selector
  }

  return result;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: this question might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that existed. I'll just post my answer as the solution and move to codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may suggest something that is much more compact and [works 20% faster](https://jsbench.me/hqkccftasg/1):

```js
const src = [...'abcdefghijklmn'],

      chunkArr = (arr, qty) =>
        arr.reduce((r,e,i) => 
          (r[i%qty].push(e),r), 
          [...Array(qty)].map(_ => []))
        
console.log(chunkArr(src, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This is Solution B really, I'm looking for Solution A.

Comment: @Nelo : the latest update implements what you call 'Solution A' and it works about 20% faster than your current code

Comment: Array.from and shift are just slow (relatively), and OP's while loop approach breaks v8 packed opts.  `Array(qty).fill().map(_=>[])` and remove ||[] check, problem solved.  Or `....fill([],qty,arr.length)` if empty arrays pointing to the same reference are acceptable.  Or stop trying to one-line it and for loop to fill in the rest.

Comment: @3limin4t0r : fixed, feel free to delete your comment as no longer relevant

Comment: @user120242 : I better like `[...Array(qty)]` than `Array(qty).fill()`, [it seems](https://jsbench.me/hqkccftasg/1) not to screw the performance

Comment: With enough iterations and large enough arrays, .fill.map is slightly faster than [...Array()].  But I guess in this case it's negligible, because the chunk size is small.  In microbenches between fill and ... it normalizes to like less than a few % difference on V8 if I remember right.  Sounds like you're already aware of this though.

Comment: Although a nice answer. I personally wouldn't sacrifice that much readability. [A normal function can just be as fast](https://jsbench.me/ockcdctr5a/1) and is a lot more readable.

Comment: @3limin4t0r : I agree, it's blazing fast. The only disadvantage, [it does not produce the expected output](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/RwryWNY?editors=0012)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov My bad, I had a typo and used `size` instead of `length`. However the point still stands. Here is the [updated JSBench](https://jsbench.me/ockcdctr5a/2). Keeping functions readable is imo worth more than speed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to note about your current approach.

1. I personally wouldn't use `if (typeof result[i] == 'undefined')`. Instead you could omit the `typeof` and do `if (result[i] === undefined)`. However since you know the value is either an array or not present at all the check `if (!result[i])` would be enough.
2. The lines `i++` and `i = (i == chunks) ? 0 : i` could be combined if you use the remainder operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder). Resulting in `i = (i + 1) % chunks`.
3. You solution only adds an empty array when it needs a new one. This will lead to an invalid result when you try to execute `into_subarrays(a, 12)` with your current solution. It is probably better to create the correct amount of arrays up front with something like `Array.from({length: chunks}, () => [])`. This will also remove the need for the *if*-statement.

Applying the above the result would look something like:

```js
function into_subarrays(array, chunks = 2) {
  array = array.slice(); // Copy array so that the original is not modified
  const result = Array.from({length: chunks}, () => []);

  for (let i = 0; array.length; i = (i + 1) % chunks) {
    result[i].push(array.shift());
  }

  return result;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 4));
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 12));
```

You could omit the `slice` if you didn't `shift` the elements out of the array.

```js
function into_subarrays(array, chunks = 2) {
  const result = Array.from({length: chunks}, () => []);

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    const chunk = result[i % chunks];
    chunk.push(array[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 4));
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 12));
```

I would like to point out that there is also an opportunity here to use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to cycle through the resulting arrays.

```js
function* cycle(iterable) {
  while (true) yield* iterable;
}

function into_subarrays(array, chunks = 2) {
  const result = Array.from({length: chunks}, () => []);
  const cycler = cycle(result);
  
  for (const item of array) {
    const chunk = cycler.next().value;
    chunk.push(item);
  }

  return result;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 4));
console.log(into_subarrays(array, 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the micro-benchmark differences will come down to these optimizations:
https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds

Your question requires more context to be relevant.  Depends on things like engine/environment specific optimizations, chunk size, data set size, and type of data (for taking advantage of packed optimizations).  Performance characteristics can vary, and it becomes a matter of opinion rather than fact as it just becomes conjecture, when the real world case is probably that more likely than not it isn't anywhere near being your bottleneck.
eg:  In React, immutability giving performance advantages for users of the library, but the React developers make use of the above linked optimizations internally.
Even withstanding all that, the relevance of the performance is debatable, and should be measured with real world data.  It's not likely these optimizations will apply to you.

For example, the generator approach not having to iterate over the entire list and build the whole list may be significantly more performant for the case that it does not have to iterate over the entire array and store everything in memory. In a microbench where it's being run many times and the challenge is to build the entire list with a homogeneous array with native level optimizations for access, it just ends up adding overhead.

A few takeaways on performance of the other answers and your demo code so far:

- [`Array.from` is slow](https://jsben.ch/XSfHE) (relatively on V8(Chrome))
- using `shift`(+push) is very slow
- accessing indexes of arrays outside their actual length breaks the fast path
- generators defer performance, and in microbench for OP's given problem only adds overhead to array access
- for small arrays almost no difference is seen.  It's almost all just object initialization
- larger chunks also closes the gap

Benchmark here: https://jsben.ch/JrtTv
[image: benchmark]

NOTE: tweaking array size and chunk size will change the results drastically

For loop implementation will outperform all the other answers due to avoidance of overhead, object initialization, and packed optimizations. Also controlled memory usage:

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const chunk = (a, n) => {
  const res = []
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const r = []
    res.push(r)
    for(let j = 0; j < (a.length/n|0)+(i<a.length%n); j++)
      r.push(a[j*n+i])
  }
  return res
}
console.log(chunk(array, 4));
console.log(chunk(array, 12));
```

a bit faster (but slower than for-loop) because of pre-allocation (and ensures array indexing optimizations):

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

const chunk = (a, n) =>
  Array(n).fill().map((_,i)=>
    Array((a.length/n|0)+(i<a.length%n)).fill().map((_,j)=>a[j*n+i]))
    
    
console.log(chunk(a,4))
console.log(chunk(a,12))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the *"`Array.from` is slow"* statement? How and from what answer do you conclude that? Do you have any benchmarks that only test the array creation variants?

Comment: Simple naive benchmark here: https://jsben.ch/XSfHE V8 link above explains part of it.  Due to iterating as an object (and special checks).  Can't find SO thread with discussion and benches.  (Relatively speaking it is an order of magnitude difference, and not speaking of real world relevance)

Comment: I personally prefer readability over speed unless speed is an actual issue. Since I find the `Array.from` method the most descriptive I tend to use that one the most. It's also performing not bad when you adjust you benchmark to the actual scenario. https://jsben.ch/c06eS However I agree with you that those micro optimizations are often not worth the trouble.

Comment: So yes, I'm not speaking of real world relevance, and I have tried to stress this strongly in my post, even bringing up specific examples.  It's extremely unlikely this will ever be your bottleneck.  Nor do I speak of readability, which is also subjective, especially in this case, where honestly I don't really see a signifciant improvement Array.from({length: n}) over Array(n)  (.fill if you're splitting hairs).  In this case the OP speaks of efficiency, and objectively speaking from a purely bench perf standpoint, Array.from will always be an order of magnitude slower than the alternatives.

Comment: Note, even then it's still 3x slower.  It is definitely a correct statement to say, "it is slow".  And when you benchmark it, when everything is just benchmark golfing and you leverage native level array access, Array.from starts to affect the numbers.  I wouldn't fault anyone for using Array.from because they feel it looks nice.  But I personally don't see it.  I don't really see how Array.from({length:n},mapFn) is more readable than Array(n).fill().map(mapFn).  I can see the merit with [...Array(n)].

Comment: It probably depends on the browser you run it in. Since in my benchmark results (https://jsben.ch/c06eS) [it's the fastest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JV4N.png) about 60% of the time. I'm running the benchmarks in Firefox 78.0.1 (64 bit).

Comment: Oh, right, Firefox optimizes things differently.  FF doesn't do the native level opts quite like V8 does.  You'll notice the number of iterations FF is able to do is significantly less, because they don't optimize array access to the same degree as eg Chrome does.  So they just end up being basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
into_subarrays(myArray, chunks=2){
  var a = myArray.slice(); //Copy array so that the original is not modified
  var i = 0;
  var result = [];
          
  while(a.length){
   //Create array if needed
   if (typeof result[i] == 'undefined'){
     result[i] = [];
   }

   result[i].push(a.shift());
   i++;
   i = (i == chunks) ? 0 : i; //Wrap around chunk selector
  }

  return result;
}
```